# RPM spec file ... am i doing it right?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have been trying to pack one of my projects into one RPM. Just looking for a little guidance as I am new to this. I am trying to pack everything i need along with each programs configurations, for my centralized logging project. I will list my spec file.. can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
Summary: Next generation system logging daemon
Name: prog-syslog-ng
Version: 3.5.6
Release: 1
License: GPL
Group: System Environment/Daemons

Source0: eventlog_0.2.13.tar.gz
Source1: libdbi_0.9.0.tar.gz
Source2: freetds-patched.tar.gz
Source3: libdbi_drivers_0.9.0.tar.gz
Source4: syslog-ng_%{version}.tar.gz
Source5: syslog-ng.conf
Source6: syslog-ng.logrotate

BuildRequires: bison, flex, gcc-c++, gcc,  glib2-devel, pkgconfig, openssl-  devel, libnet-devel, libesmtp, hiredis, git, vim, net-tools,

Provides: syslog
```

and now the prep section..

```
%prep

%setup -D -c -a 0
%setup -D -c -a 1
%setup -D -c -a 2
%setup -D -c -a 3
%setup -D -c -a 4
```

onto the build section...

```
%build
cd ./eventlog-0.2.13
%configure
make %{_smp_mflags}

cd ../libdbi-0.9.0
%configure
make %{_smp_mflags}

cd ../freetds-0.91.112
ODBCDIR=`odbc_config --prefix || true`
if test ! -r "$ODBCDIR/include/sql.h"; then
        ODBCDIR=/usr/local
fi
if test ! -r "$ODBCDIR/include/sql.h"; then
        ODBCDIR=/usr
fi
%configure --with-tdsver=7.1
make %{_smp_mflags}

cd ../libdbi-drivers-0.9.0
%configure ./configure --with-dbi-incdir=/usr/local/include/dbi --with-dbi-libdir=/usr/local/lib  --with-freetds --with-freetds-incdir=%{_includedir} --with-freetds-libdir=%{_libdir}
# --with-dbi-incdir=%{buildroot}/usr/include/dbi --with-dbi-libdir=%{buildroot}/usr/lib64 --with-mssql --with-freetds
make %{_smp_mflags}

cd ../syslog-ng-3.5.6
GEOIP_LIBS=-lGeoIP; export GEOIP_LIBS; \
%configure \
    --prefix=%{_prefix} \
    --sysconfdir=%{_sysconfdir}/syslog-ng \
    --localstatedir=%{_sharedstatedir}/syslog-ng \
    --datadir=%{_datadir}/syslog-ng \
    --with-module-dir=/%{_libdir}/syslog-ng \
    --with-systemdsystemunitdir=%{_unitdir} \
    --with-ivykis=system \
    --with-libmongo-client=system \
    --with-embedded-crypto \
    --enable-man-pages \
    --enable-ipv6 \
    --enable-tcp-wrapper \
    --enable-pcre \
    --enable-spoof-source \
    --enable-linux-caps \
    --enable-sql \
    --enable-json \
    --enable-ssl \
    --enable-smtp \
    --enable-geoip \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --enable-dynamic-linking \
    --enable-systemd \
    --enable-redis \
    --disable-amqp \
    --with-librabbitmq-client=no
# remove rpath
sed -i 's|^hardcode_libdir_flag_spec=.*|hardcode_libdir_flag_spec=""|g' libtool
sed -i 's|^runpath_var=LD_RUN_PATH|runpath_var=DIE_RPATH_DIE|g' libtool

make %{_smp_mflags}
```

The install section ...

```
%install
cd ./eventlog-0.2.13
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} install
# we build into /usr/lib,
# but we want the library (but not the devel stuff) in /lib
install -d -m 755 %{buildroot}/%{_lib}
pushd %{buildroot}%{_libdir}
mv libevtlog.so.* %{buildroot}/%{_lib}
ln -sf ../../%{_lib}/libevtlog.so.*.* libevtlog.so

cd %{_builddir}/prog-syslog-ng-3.5.6/libdbi-0.9.0
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} install

#rm -f ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_libdir}/libdbi.a
#rm -f ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_libdir}/libdbi.la

cd ../freetds-0.91.112
make DESTDIR="$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" install

cd ../libdbi-drivers-0.9.0
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} install

# Headers
install -d %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/dbi
for file in $(find drivers/ -type f -name \*.h)
do
    install -m0644 ${file}  %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/dbi/
done

# Docs
install -d %{buildroot}%{_docdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0
for file in drivers/*/{TODO,AUTHORS,README}
do
    driver=$(echo $file|awk -F/ '{print $2}')
    newfile=$(basename $file)
    install -m0644 $file %{buildroot}%{_docdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/$newfile.$driver
done
for pdf in drivers/*/dbd_*.pdf
do
    install -m0644 $pdf %{buildroot}%{_docdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/
done
for dir in $(find drivers/ -type d -name dbd_\*)
do
    cp -pr $dir %{buildroot}%{_docdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/
done

#rm -f ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_libdir}/dbd/*.a
#rm -f ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_libdir}/dbd/*.la

cd ../syslog-ng-3.5.6
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} install

%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/syslog-ng/conf.d
%{__install} -p -m 644 %{SOURCE5} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/logrotate.d
%{__install} -p -m 644 %{SOURCE6} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/logrotate.d/syslog

# create the local state dir
%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_sharedstatedir}/syslog-ng

# install the main library header files
%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/syslog-ng
%{__install} -p -m 644 config.h %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/syslog-ng
%{__install} -p -m 644 lib/*.h %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/syslog-ng

# install vim files
%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/syslog-ng
%{__install} -p -m 644 contrib/syslog-ng.vim %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/syslog-ng
for vimver in 73 ; do
    %{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/vim/vim$vimver/syntax
    cd %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/vim/vim$vimver/syntax
    ln -s ../../../syslog-ng/syslog-ng.vim .
    cd -
done

%{__install} -d -m 755 %{buildroot}/usr/lib64/syslog-ng

find %{buildroot} -name "*.la" -exec rm -f {} \;

# remove some extra testing related files
rm %{buildroot}/%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/syslog-ng-test.pc
rm %{buildroot}/%{_libdir}/syslog-ng/libtest/libsyslog-ng-test.a

[ -d "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6" ] || ./install-sh -d "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6"
./install-sh NEWS \
  ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6/NEWS
./install-sh AUTHORS \
  ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6/AUTHORS
./install-sh COPYING \
  ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6/COPYING
```

And now the Files section ... this is a bit messy.. i know ..

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)

############ EVENTLOG FILES #########################

#%doc AUTHORS ChangeLog COPYING CREDITS NEWS README
%{_libdir}/libevtlog.so
%{_libdir}/libevtlog.a
#%{_libdir}/libevtlog.la
#%{libdir}/libevtlog.

#%doc doc/*
%{_libdir}/libevtlog.so
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/eventlog.pc
%dir %{_includedir}/eventlog
%{_includedir}/eventlog
%{_libdir}/libevtlog.a

############ LIBDBI FILES #########################

#%doc AUTHORS
#%doc ChangeLog
#%doc COPYING
#%doc README
%{_libdir}/libdbi.*
#%doc TODO
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-0.9.0/programmers-guide.pdf
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-0.9.0/programmers-guide/
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-0.9.0/driver-guide.pdf
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-0.9.0/driver-guide/
%{_includedir}/dbi/
%{_libdir}/libdbi.so
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/dbi.pc

############ FREETDS FILES #####################

#%doc AUTHORS BUGS COPYING* ChangeLog INSTALL NEWS README
%{_bindir}/*
%{_mandir}/man?/*
%{_libdir}/libct.so.*
%{_libdir}/libsybdb.so.*
%config %{_sysconfdir}/*
%{_libdir}/*.a
#%{_libdir}/*.la
%{_libdir}/*.so
%{_includedir}/*
%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdfreetds.so
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/freetds-0.91.112/userguide
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/freetds-0.91.112/images
%doc %{_defaultdocdir}/freetds-0.91.112/reference
############## LIBDBI-DRIVERS FILES ###############

#%doc drivers/mysql/dbd_mysql/*.html
#%doc drivers/mysql/*.pdf
#%doc drivers/pgsql/dbd_pgsql/*.html
#%doc drivers/pgsql/*.pdf
#%doc drivers/sqlite3/dbd_sqlite3/*.html
#%doc drivers/sqlite3/*.pdf
%dir %{_libdir}/dbd/

#%files -n libdbi-dbd-mysql#
%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdfreetds.so
%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdfreetds.a
#%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdfreetds.la
%{_includedir}/dbi/*.h

#%files -n libdbi-dbd-pgsql
#%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdpgsql.*

#%files -n libdbi-dbd-sqlite
#%{_libdir}/dbd/libdbdsqlite3.*


################# SYSLOG-ng FILES #################


%{_sbindir}/syslog-ng
%{_sbindir}/syslog-ng-ctl

%{_bindir}/loggen
%{_mandir}/*
%docdir %{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6
%{_prefix}/share/doc/syslog-ng-3.5.6/*
%config(noreplace) /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
#%ifnos aix5.2
#/etc/rc.d/init.d/syslog-ng
#%config(noreplace) /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
#%endif


###################################################
  %{_bindir}/pdbtool
   %{_bindir}/update-patterndb

   %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/*
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/filter/*
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/ivykis/*
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/libtest/*
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/logproto/*
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/parser/parser-expr-parser.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/parser/parser-expr.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/rewrite/rewrite-expr-parser.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/rewrite/rewrite-expr.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/rewrite/rewrite-set-tag.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/rewrite/rewrite-set.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/rewrite/rewrite-subst.h
 #  %{_includedir}/syslog-ng/template/templates.h
   %{_libdir}/libsyslog-ng-3.5.6.so
   %{_libdir}/libsyslog-ng.so

   %{_libdir}/syslog-ng/*

   /lib64/libevtlog.so.0
   /lib64/libevtlog.so.0.0.0

   %{_sbindir}/syslog-ng-ctl
   %{_sbindir}/syslog-ng

   %{_prefix}/%{_lib}/syslog-ng/*

 %{_datadir}/include/scl/rewrite/cc-mask.conf
 %{_datadir}/include/scl/syslogconf/README
 %{_datadir}/include/scl/syslogconf/convert-syslogconf.awk
 %{_datadir}/include/scl/syslogconf/plugin.conf
 %{_datadir}/include/scl/system/plugin.conf

  %{_datadir}/tools/cfg-grammar.y
  %{_datadir}/tools/lex-rules.am
  %{_datadir}/tools/merge-grammar.pl

  %{_datadir}/xsd/patterndb-1.xsd
  %{_datadir}/xsd/patterndb-2.xsd
  %{_datadir}/xsd/patterndb-3.xsd
  %{_datadir}/xsd/patterndb-4.xsd

%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_db2/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_ingres/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_mysql/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_msql/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_oracle/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_pgsql/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_sqlite/*
%{_defaultdocdir}/libdbi-drivers-0.9.0/dbd_sqlite3/*


   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafamqp.so
  /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libaffile.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafmongodb.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafprog.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafsmtp.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafsocket-notls.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafsocket-tls.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafsocket.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafsql.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafstomp.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libafuser.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libbasicfuncs.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libconfgen.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libcryptofuncs.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libcsvparser.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libdbparser.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libjson-plugin.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/liblinux-kmsg-format.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libredis.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslogformat.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libsystem-source.so
   /usr/lib/syslog-ng/libtfgeoip.so

   /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/syslog-ng.pc

   /usr/share/include/scl/pacct/plugin.conf
   /usr/share/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syslog-ng.vim
```

Any help or direction in actually making this work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why are you packing this all into a single RPM? Does your OS not have packages for many of these things that you could use? And layer configuration on top of via package, kickstart, config management tool (ansible, puppet, chef, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a RedHat installation (syslog-ng part derived from my EPEL package). Everything is available in the distribution or EPEL, except for FreeTDS and the FreeTDS driver for libdbi. So I'd also suggest to package only that (package FreeTDS and modify the the existing libdbi-driver package to support FreeTDS).

On the package manager side you will need to install syslog-ng-sql and libdbi-driver-freetds and these will install the necessary dependencies.